# Why does .meteor have a .gitignore file?

Tags: version-control, meteor, gitignore

I am creating a new meteor app and would like to put the whole thing under git source control. When cloning a working copy of my meteor directory, meteor gives : run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

After inspecting the .meteor directory, I see that the files in here are being excluded in my local clone.

Is there a particular reason this is done?

Comment: Those files change ever time you run the app, and even while you are running the app. This prevents a mass of meaningless commits. If you want to clone a meteor project you'll have to add that folder yourself, although I'm not sure what command you should use for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I put in a meteor .gitignore file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728956/what-should-i-put-in-a-meteor-gitignore-file)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

as @Swadq already pointed about, the .meteor directory is Meteor's directory. It contains  a folder and a file.

The `local` directory contains the compiled version of your application and some database information (lock-file and the actual raw data of mongodb). This of course should not be included in your VCS.

The `package` file contains all packages meteor should load for your application. This is of course important and must be included in your VCS. More importantly: **this file is checked for to determine if the current directory is a meteor application**. If you don't include this you'll loose the packages you relay on and the ability to simply run the app. using `meteor`.

So ideally your .gitignore file only should contain `.meteor\local` but not `.meteor\packages`. When using `meteorite` the `.gitignore` file should contain `.meteor\meteorite` as well.